# Don't understand why pgrep doesn't work in a bash script with sudo

Tags: bash, shell-script, pgrep

I'm trying to detect whether the zoom program is running. I also need sudo privileges in my bash script to install it with dpkg.

If I use `pgrep -f "zoom" >/dev/null 2>&1`, the return code `echo $?` will be correctly set to 0 if zoom is running and to 1 if not found.

By using `sudo`, `pgrep` picked up two additional processes: the `sudo pgrep etc.` one and the `pgrep etc.` child process of the `sudo` one. This didn't work so I had to use a 'hacky workaround': `sudo pgrep -f "[z]oom" >/dev/null 2>&1` did the trick: the regex made sure `pgrep` processes aren't added to the results.

So now with `sudo pgrep -f "[z]oom" >/dev/null 2>&1 ;` I have `echo $?` set to 1 if the process is not running and 0 if it's running. Perfect.

But when I added this in my bash script (which I run with `sudo`):

```
if pgrep -f "[z]oom" 2>&1 ; then
    echo $?
    echo "zoom is running"
```

This no longer works and it *always* says that the zoom process is running (so it always returns 0 even if zoom is *not* running).

Why is that?

Comment: Does the name of the script include the word 'zoom'?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour, unless when, like @Haxiel suggest, use the search term in the name of the script.

Comment: You should avoid using the `-f` flag in `pgrep` since there could be many unexpected consequences. For instance, if someone else is running `grep zoom` at the same time, pgrep will also catch it. You should use the exact name of the process instead. If you're not sure because the process name is different then the command name, you can run first: `ps -o comm -p $(pgrep -f zoom)` to find the process name, and then pgrep for it without `-f`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `-f`. Just use

```
pgrep -x zoom >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: You assume that the process name is exactly "zoom", which might not be the case. That's why I suggested in another comment to run `ps -o comm -p $(pgrep -f zoom)` first to find the exact process name, and then he can use it with `-x`.